# HTML5 digital clock animation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm new to HTML5 and web programming. I've picked up a few basics and had started a bit on canvas based animations. However, while attempting to create a digital clock based animation I've had no success. The code validates properly on JSLint and is expected to work, but instead shows nothing.

Here is the source http://jsfiddle.net/kuydB/

Here is the JavaScript source:

```
var filterStrength = 20;
var frameTime = 0, lastLoop = new Date(), thisLoop;
var canvas, ctx;


function startWatch() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    var currentDateTime = new Date();

    var hours = currentDateTime.getHours();
    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    var minutes = currentDateTime.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    var seconds = currentDateTime.getSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    var timeString = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

    ctx.font = 'bold ' + canvas.width / 4 + 'px sans-serif';

    var dim = ctx.measureText(timeString);

    var y = (canvas.height - 30) / 2;
    var x = (canvas.width - dim.width) / 2;

    ctx.fillText(timeString, x, y);   

      var thisFrameTime = (thisLoop=new Date()) - lastLoop;
      frameTime+= (thisFrameTime - frameTime) / filterStrength;
      lastLoop = thisLoop;

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    setIntervalTimer(startWatch,1000);
    var fpsOut = document.getElementById('fps');
    setInterval(function(){
      fpsOut.innerHTML = (1000/frameTime).toFixed(1) + " fps";
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: The JavaScript console (in Chromium 22/Ubuntu 12.10) reports: `Uncaught ReferenceError: setIntervalTimer is not defined`.

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of JS, then this intro to chrome's debugging tools might be worth a read. It's a little dated, but it's a fantastic intro to the topic:

http://jtaby.com/2012/04/23/modern-web-development-part-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuydB/1/)

```
var filterStrength = 20;
var frameTime = 0, lastLoop = new Date(), thisLoop;
var canvas, ctx;


function startWatch() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    var currentDateTime = new Date();

    var hours = currentDateTime.getHours();
    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    var minutes = currentDateTime.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    var seconds = currentDateTime.getSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    var timeString = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

    ctx.font = 'bold ' + canvas.width / 4 + 'px sans-serif';

    var dim = ctx.measureText(timeString);

    var y = (canvas.height - 30) / 2;
    var x = (canvas.width - dim.width) / 2;

    ctx.fillText(timeString, x, y);   

      var thisFrameTime = (thisLoop=new Date()) - lastLoop;
      frameTime+= (thisFrameTime - frameTime) / filterStrength;
      lastLoop = thisLoop;

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    setInterval(startWatch,1000); //here you had a syntax error you typed setIntervalTimer instead of setInterval
    var fpsOut = document.getElementById('fps');
    setInterval(function(){
      fpsOut.innerHTML = (1000/frameTime).toFixed(1) + " fps";
    }, 1000);
});
​
```

Comment: hope this helped you :) its working now!

Comment: A 15 year old web programmer solved it.. Keep it up... :)

Comment: @hytriutucx, this should not be an answer, imo. Aspiring Aqib, you simply changed nothing but the `setInterval` - this could have been mentioned in a comment !! The whole code is same, word by word, as was posted in question

Comment: @OmShankar: please don't advise folks to answer questions via comments. Granted, this answer could be improved *considerably* by reducing the code to just that which is relevant and then using the space to explain what the problem was / why the solution works... So suggest *that*.

Comment: @Shog9, agree, that was my point - just `that` part. Btw, you should check an ideal scenario, where **comments are sufficient** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108345

Comment: @OmShankar, that's a closed question that links to a duplicate with 7 real answers. So I'd be hesitant to call it an ideal scenario. Furthermore, comments are intended to help a person clarify the question or to help a person improve an answer. Comments are *not* intended to answer a question. See [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more guidance. Hope this helps!

Comment: @jmort253, It was closed only 13 hrs ago, before writing this comment. I cannot be blamed for calling it an ideal scenario in the past. The comment idea you mentioned however is right. Thanks